# How to find numbered rows in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a SQL Server database and would like to find a numbered column.

Suppose I have below values in a column

```
column_A
```

I have tried this:

```
select * 
from Table1 
where column_A like '^([0-9a-z])\1+'
```

but the regex doesn't seem to work in SQL Server.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply try like following.

```
select * from Table1 where '0123456789' like '%' + column_A + '%'
```

The same thing can be done using recursive CTE like the following query.

```
declare @table table(column_A varchar(10))

insert into @table select '123456'
insert into @table select '345678'
insert into @table select '214562'
insert into @table select '457215'
insert into @table select '456789'


;with cte as (
          select  v.column_A os, v.column_A, 1 as m
          from @table v
          union all
          select os,stuff(column_A, 1, 1, ''),
                case when cast(left(column_A, 1) as int) +1 = cast(left(stuff(column_A, 1, 1, ''),1) as int)  then 1 else 0 end as m
          from cte
          where column_A > ''   
         )
    select os
    from cte
    where column_A <>'' and m=1
    group by os 
    having count(m) =len(os)
```

Output

```
os
-----
123456
345678
456789
```