# how to solve Error converting data type varchar to bigint. the queries is select ID from Table1 where '0123456789' like '%' + ID + '%'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying out thìs [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74259050/how-to-find-consecutive-numbers-like-123456-in-a-column-in-sql-server) using queries:

```
select ID from Table1 where '0123456789' like '%' + ID + '%'
```

and the follow error show up:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3 Error converting data type varchar
> to bigint.

What did I do wrong?

I expected it return ID with consecutive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely coming from the `LIKE` expression (no pun intended).  Try this version which explicitly casts the `ID` to text:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM Table1
WHERE '0123456789' LIKE '%' + CAST(ID AS varchar(12)) + '%';
```

I speculate that the `varchar to bigint` error is happening because one of SQL Server's attempts to make the `LIKE` work is casting the `'%'` string literals to big integers, to match the type of the `ID` column.  Obviously, that won't work.

Comment: :D. this work . i see that why it doesn't work.